# Is there a function to add a column if missing and do nothing if already present?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

Say I have a data.frame and I don't know if the data.frame contains a certain column (e.g., because I've read it from a file). But I want to run code that assumes that the column is there. Is there a function in the tidyverse or another package that adds a column with a certain name and type if missing but does nothing if the column already exists?

I've coded this:

```r
add_col_if_missing <- function(df, add_col, add_type) {
  empty_df <- df
  empty_df[add_col] <- add_type(nrow(df))
  empty_df <- empty_df[0, ]
  
  df |> 
    dplyr::left_join(
      empty_df,
      by = colnames(df),
      suffix = c("", ".drop")
    ) |> 
    dplyr::select(-ends_with(".drop"))
}
```

Example:

```r
df1 <- tibble::tibble(
  id = c(1, 2, 3)
)

add_col_if_missing(
  df1,
  add_col = "x",
  add_type = character
)
# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#      id x    
#   <dbl> <chr>
# 1     1 NA   
# 2     2 NA   
# 3     3 NA   

df2 <- tibble::tibble(
  id = c(1, 2, 3),
  x = c("a", "b", "c")
)

add_col_if_missing(
  df2,
  add_col = "x",
  add_type = character
)
# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#      id x    
#   <dbl> <chr>
# 1     1 a    
# 2     2 b    
# 3     3 c
```

But I'd prefer to use a built-in/packaged function.

Comment: Your `left_join` approach seems overcomplicated. `if(!col %in% names(df)) df[[col]] = NA`. You can use `NA_integer_` or `NA_real_` or `NA_character_` etc. for the column type.

Comment: gregors answer is the way to go here

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for tibble's add_column
in your case i think it´s something like:

```
#columns you want to add
minimum_columns<- c(x=NA,y=NA,z=NA)
#adding those columns to df1
df1<- add_column(df1,!!!minimum_columns[setdiff(names(minimum_columns),names(df1))])
```